# Converting LLA (lat, long, alt) to ENU (east, north, up) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I converted LLA (lat, long, alt) to ENU (east, north, up) in MATLAB using mapping toolbox but failed to view in the ArcMap. In ArcMap, it is viewing as single point.

Is there any other way to convert and view in ArcMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: What is it that you're starting from? Is it a CSV (or other text delimited file) file with lat, lon and altitude? or Excel or DBF or MS Access (JET)... Can we assume that your lat/lon are WGS84/Geographic? What coordinate system do you want your Eastings and Northings in? Is altitude and up in the same units (both metres, both feet etc..) or does that require conversion also? (feet to metres for example).

Comment: You might find http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm helps if you have tabular XY(Z) data to import into ArcMap. Define your input spatial reference as your geographic spatial reference then using the project tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm transform the points to your EN(u) coordinate system then optionally AddXY to add your E,N,u to the feature class table http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm.

Comment: I downloaded data from the Open Street Map which is having lla coordinate reference system and file format is 'osm'. But now converted into ENU(East,North,up)  in 'osm' file format in MATLAB.

Comment: But I don't have it in tabular form. It is a 'osm' format. Initially it is having WGS84,

Comment: You may be able to come close using a custom orthographic or "Local" projected coordinate system, setting the ENU center to the latitude/longitude of origin parameters.

Comment: OSM is an XML format https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML#Example_OSM_XML_file which is not an Esri native format, this link might help you https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-editor-for-openstreetmap there are tools to import, read https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/3351/how-can-i-import-osm-data-into-esri for more info. Use the project tool to convert to your E,N coordinate system. Have you tried zooming in on the Esri *single point* (select all, zoom to selected) it's possible that your layer extent isn't shrunk to the feature extent so it zooms right out.

Comment: I selected all features and did zoom to layer. But it is not visible, still it is single feature.